# Data is not getting update in the table when I click on custom refresh button in the page

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have to add one refresh button through angular material icon in my page which does `$http` call to fetch latest data and update the view. I have added the `$watch` to check for updates. Below is the javascript file for the same

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('viewController', function($scope, $http) {

$scope.fetch = function() {

    $scope.gridOptions = {
        data : []
    }
    $http({
        method : 'GET',
        url : '/ServiceLookupMS/webapi/resource/gating-info',
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(function(response) {

        $scope.gridOptions.data = response.data;
        $scope.$watch('gridOptions', function(newValue){
            $scope.gridOptions = newValue;
        });
    })
}

$scope.refresh = function(){
    $scope.fetch();
}
```

});

I have using `$scope.gridOptions` in my HTML page like this and loaded in to the table. `ng-init="fetch()"` loads initial data and `ng-click="refresh()"` for refresh.

```
<div ng-controller="viewController" ng-cloak ng-init="fetch()">
<div grid-data id='gtaingInfo' grid-options="gridOptions"
    grid-actions="gridActions">
.................
        <div layout-gt-xs="row" layout-xs="column" layout-align="end center">
        <div layout="row" layout-align="start end">
            <md-tooltip md-direction="left">Refresh Grid</md-tooltip>
            <md-icon md-svg-src="images/ic_refresh_black_24px.svg" ng-click="refresh()"></md-icon>
        </div>
...................
...................
<tbody>
                <tr grid-item>
                    <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric"><span
                        ng-bind="item.appName"></span></td>
                    <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric"
                        ng-bind="item.apiName"></td>
                    <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric"
                        ng-bind="item.baseUrl"></td>
                    <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric"
                        ng-bind="item.gatingEnabled"></td>
                    <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric"><md-menu-bar>
                        <md-menu> <md-icon class="material-icons"
                            ng-click="$mdMenu.open()">more_vert</md-icon> <md-menu-content
                            layout="column" width="50px"> <md-menu-item>
                        <md-button class="md-primary" ng-click="">Edit</md-button></md-menu-item> <md-menu-item>
                        <md-button class="md-primary" ng-click="">Delete</md-button></md-menu-item> </md-menu-content> </md-menu> </md-menu-bar></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

When i click on the refresh button, `$http` is call is happening but the updated data in loaded in the view. Can anyone please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `$scope.gridOptions.data = response.data;
        $scope.$watch('gridOptions', function(newValue){
            $scope.gridOptions = newValue;
        });` seems confusing. Why you watching same variable and updating again.

Comment: I don't know. I started googling about it. So I just tried based on search. I guess I am wrong. But `$scope.gridOtions` is getting updated in the JS. But it's not updated in HTML page.

Comment: remove watch and check. It should work.

Comment: Yes, I tried just now. Still HTML is not updated.

Comment: write: `setTimeout(function (){$scope.$apply()},0)` just after `$scope.gridOptions.data = response.data;`. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Still no. my custom refresh is not working. But when I do F5, that works. I am still not understanding why? Is it coz of the way I used in HTML page? I used libraries for data-grid.

Comment: Hey Ved, I solved it. Your first comment gave me hint. I assigned `$http` payload to some temp object and I tried `$watch` on temp object. It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

I assigned `$http` payload to some temporary object and I tried `$watch` on temp object. It worked